Power supply does not have diodes but still works
This question arose from another thread in SE. There is a tube amplifier with certain parts powered by a center tapped line of transformer. Strangely, that line is not rectified. It doesn't have any diodes, it only has filter capacitors. I cannot understand how this works. Below is the circuit.  The line is question highlighted with yellow:


You can think of it like part of the bridge rectifier is doing double duty.
For the high voltage you have a full wave bridge rectifier:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For the lower voltage you have a center tapped full wave rectifier:

simulate this circuit
This give you a second voltage that is roughly half what the high voltage is.
In many tube circuits the rectifier is a center tapped full wave rectifier using a vacuum tube rectifier in the same sort of configuration, the transformer secondaries go to the plates (anodes) of the rectifier tube with the cathodes being grounded and the positive voltage taken from the transformer center tap. Different voltages are often obtained from this by using a voltage divider with large high power resistors. This circuit just adds a couple more rectifiers to get two different voltages without having to waste power in a divider.
In amateur radio this circuit is known as the "economy" power supply and is mentioned in some older versions of the ARRL Radio Amateur's Handbook.
Here it is from the 1981 version:



Ok, now i have started to grab the idea.

The yellow highlighted nets can be regarded as the mid-voltage point on the transformer secondary and, given that the bridge rectifier coupled to the outer wires of the secondary produces plus and minus DC supplies, the highlighted yellow nets can be regarded as 0 volts DC.
It's a common trick used in many designs. Here's a similar example: -

On your design, the -Ve voltage is in fact ground/0 volts but, that's just a name. Functionally it's the same.

Here's a simplified version of the power supply circuit.

It's a full-wave bridge rectifier circuit for an output voltage of + 2 V and another full-wave rectifier circuit, that uses the transformer centre-tap, for an output voltage of + V.
The latter is separately shown below for easier understanding.

The 'missing diodes' are part of the bridge rectifier.

Just regard the diodes as switches. The plus output of the diode bridge is at any time connected to that end of the transformer coil which happens to be positive.
Vice versa, the minus output of the bridge is at any moment of time connected to the other end of the transformer coil, which happens to be negative.
At any moment in time, the midpoint of the transformer coil is simply at the mid voltage of the diode bridge output.
You could select any point to be at "zero" (or "ground"), and measure the voltages of all other points of the circuit relative to that selected zero point.
If you connect the midpoint of the transformer coil to ground, the bridge outputs will be a symmetrical plus and minus power supply.
Or, if you connect the minus output of the bridge to ground, the transformer midpoint will be at half the voltage of the plus output of the bridge.
If you just use the plus and minus outputs of the bridge, and do not connect a load between the transformer midpoint and the bridge minus output, then all four diodes carry the same average current. But in case you DO connect a load between midpoint and minus, then of course the current in the minus output is higher than that in the plus output, and the corresponding two "minus" diodes carry a higher current than the two "plus" diodes. Hence the saying in one of the other answers that this can be seen as a combination of a full diode bridge and a half diode bridge.
